# Hive: Insert overwrite directory limit size of each part file

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm processing the output of the below Hive query:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/main_directory/table' 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' SELECT * FROM table;
```

one part file at a time sequentially in Python. However, some of the files are too big and the Python script is failing with memory error. 
Therefore, I need to limit the size of each of the output part files to ~300 MB or ~250K rows.